# INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
protected function store_credentials($config_file_path = 'envato_credentials_config.json') {
    $credentials_config = $this->get_envato_config($config_file_path);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO credentials (api_key, username, last_update) VALUES (?, ?, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE api_key = values(api_key), username = values(username), last_update = values(last_update)";
    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $credentials_config['API'], $credentials_config['User']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But what happens is that I always get duplicate entries when it's executed, if it's executed again, instead of updating it runs again adding another two entries. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the columns you are inserting needs to be a primary key or have a unique constraint.

Comment: and also, id mustn't be auto-incrementing primary key ;)

Comment: Oh, because it's auto-increment, so I should set it to PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE but not auto-increment ?

Comment: You have to decide what is unique. Username? Or API-key? Add a unique constraint on one of those or one of them as primary key of the column.

Comment: @barsju - It works now, without any problems :) Could I add a condition for the update ? And how would I proceed if I don't want it to do anything if the fields are already filled ?

Comment: I don't think so. The syntax doesn't seem to support that. So you'll likely have to handle that in php.

Comment: @barsju - I see, the thing is that, there's a field called last_update which is set as datetime. And I only want to update ( if the insert isn't executed that in case if the fields are empty ) if the time in the last_update is greater than 2 hours than the time that I'm running the query. How could I do this without complicating it ?

Comment: I did, and they're saying I'm spamming and I got no answer yet :)